# probability distribution function and quantile function for normal distribution in R

Tags: r, self-study, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, mean

I've studied statistics before but I've forgotten quite a lot, but decided to pick it up again along with learning how to use R. I need help with this question: (I've translated from my Swedish book so pardon if my translation is a tad shoddy.)

> The diameter for axles that are manufactured is considered a stochastic variable $\xi$. At quality control the axles that are thicker than 1.01 mm and thinner than 0.99 mm are sorted out. It has been found that $P(ξ > 1.01) = 8\%$ and $P(ξ < 0.99) = 2\%$. Assume that $ξ \sim N(μ,σ)$. Decide the values of $μ$ and $σ$.

First of all, I'm completely stuck. I figured I could do something with

$$P(0.99 < ξ < 1.01) = P((0.99-μ)/σ < (ξ-μ)/σ < (1.01-μ)/σ)$$

but after that I'm unable to figure out what to do. Could somebody give me a hint?

My second question is, how would one go about to find these missing values in R? I've had similar issues before trying to solve problems of algebraic nature in R and I've yet to find a way to do it.

Comment: When working with normal distributions (and any other location-scale family), *convert all measurements to Z-scores.*  That process takes $\mu$ and $\sigma$ out of the picture altogether, simplifying everything.  At the end, Z-scores can easily be re-expressed in terms of the original measurements.  Thus, your problem asks you to find the Z-scores associated with the $100-8=92$ and $2$ percentage points of the standard Normal distribution.  `R` offers `qnorm` for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \Pr\left( \frac{\xi - \mu} \sigma > \frac{1.01 - \mu} \sigma \right) = 0.08. \\[10pt]
& \Pr\left( \frac{\xi - \mu} \sigma < \frac{0.99 - \mu} \sigma \right) = 0.02. \\[10pt]
\text{Therefore } & \frac{1.01 - \mu} \sigma \approx 1.40572 \text{ and } \frac{0.99 - \mu} \sigma \approx -2.053749.
\end{align}
$$
1.40572 - (-2.053749) = 3.458821 \approx \frac{1.01 - \mu} \sigma - \frac{0.99 - \mu} \sigma = \frac {0.02} \sigma.
$$
From the line above you can find $\sigma$, then plug that into either of the expressions in the line above beginning with "Therefore", and find $\mu$.